# AWS Python CDK - Account specific resource on policy creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an AWS policy to grant the `kms:CreateKey` permission to a principal. I'm having trouble defining the Resource part of the policy.

By reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-api-permissions-reference.html) I found out that I can specify something like this:

```
arn:AWS_partition_name:kms:AWS_region:AWS_account_ID:*
```

instead of the regular `*`.

My question is, how can I achieve this using the Python CDK?

Comment: Can you add the code you used to create the resource? It'll be really helpful for me to write the answer and for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using predefined env variables in Python related to AWS CLI/AWS CDK. in this case you can do it in a following way:

```
arn = f"arn:AWS_partition_name:kms:{os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')}:{os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT')}:*"
```

here is the full picture how to add it role:

```
role = _iam.Role(self, "lambda_emr_launcher_role", 
                 role_name="_trackit-emr-launcher-role",
                 description="Service role for self-titled Lamdbda",
                 assumed_by=_iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
                 managed_policies=[_iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole")],
                                   inline_policies={
                                         "Policy_KMS": _iam.PolicyDocument(statements=[
                                             _iam.PolicyStatement(effect=_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                                                                  principals=["principal_example1"],
                                                                  resources=[f"arn:AWS_partition_name:kms:{os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')}:{os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT')}:*"],
                                                                  actions=["kms:CreateKey"])])})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IAM policy like this:

```py
iam.PolicyStatement(
    # effect is optional.  It can be DENY or ALLOW, and it defaults to ALLOW
    effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,

    # Specifies a list of actions this principal is allowed/denied to call.
    actions=[
        # Specify a specific action
        'kms:CreateKey',
        # Or, you can specify all actions of a specific service:
        'kms:*',
    ],

    # Resources this principal can act on. 
    resources=[
        # All keys in your account, in your region
        'arn:aws:kms:<YOUR REGION>:<YOUR ACCOUNT ID>:key/*',
        
        # All aliases in your account, in your region
        'arn:aws:kms:<YOUR REGION>:<YOUR ACCOUNT ID>:alias/*',
    ],
)
```

I **very highly** recommend playing around in the [interactive IAM Policy editor](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies$new), which gives a fantastic view of all required/possible things you can do when creating a policy, including advanced ARN composition.